# Vue Allow Parent's Click Event to be Triggered on Child

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an accordion element that is triggered by a button.  Inside the button I have some text and a span with a +.  When clicking the text on the button my accordion toggles as expected, but when clicking the span with the + I get an error and the accordion doesn't toggle. Adding stop.prevent helps with the js error, but nothing happens when clicking the plus which I need it to do.

My question is how can I allow for the accordion to toggle accordingly no matter where inside the button I am clicking?

Relevant code:

```
<ul class="accordion js-accordion">
        @{int i = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model.FaqEntries)
        {
            <li @(i == 0 && Model.ExpandFirstItem ? "data-open='true'" : "") id="@item.Name">
                <button type="button" v-on:click="handleToggleClick" v-on:keydown.enter="handleToggleClick">
                    @item.Title
                    <span v-on:click.stop.prevent>+</span>
                </button>
                <div class="rich-text">@Html.Raw(@item.Content)</div>
            </li>
            i++;
        }
    </ul>
```

VUE

```
handleToggleClick: function (event) {
            if ((this.isMobileOnly && breakpoint() !== "large") || !this.isMobileOnly) {

                const btn = event.target;
                const content = btn.nextElementSibling;
                const parent = btn.parentElement;

                // If the accordion title is a link or header, don't open/close the accordion item
                if (btn.tagName === "A") {
                    return;
                }

                if (parent.classList.contains(this.toggleClass)) {
                    this.closeItem(btn, content, parent);

                } else {
                    // Close all other open accordion items
                    Array.from(this.$el.querySelectorAll(`.${this.toggleClass}`)).map(item => {
                        this.closeItem(item.querySelector(".accordion__header"), item.querySelector(".accordion__content"), item);
                    });

                    this.openItem(btn, content, parent)
                    setTimeout(() => { scrollToElement(btn) }, this.animationDuration + 1)

                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I added

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to the span and now all is good.